Python Parsing (separate statements and/or blocks) a C# code - regex or machine state
I need to parsing a C# code. Just separate the statements, considering break lines. Need to ignore comments, multiline comments, verbatim strings   and multiline verbating strings.
What i try...
I read the file into a variable and then split by break lines (because i need the original line number)... then i add the line number with a pattern, then i break the string by characters ;, {, }
and remove the patterns not needed (keep the first one)...
   
   with open("./program.cs", "r") as f:
        prg=[]
        for number, line in enumerate(f): 
            prg.append(f"<#<{number}>#>{line}")       
        dotnet_lines=re.split(r'[;\{\}]',"".join(prg))
        for i in range(len(dotnet_lines)):
            dotnet_lines[i] = dotnet_lines[i].replace("\n","")
            dotnet_lines[i] = re.sub(r'(.)(\<#\<[0-9]+\>#\>)',r'\1',dotnet_lines[i])
        # Result....
        for ln in dotnet_lines:
            ocorrencia=ln.find('>#>')+3
            line=ln[ocorrencia:]
            number=re.sub('[<#>]','',ln[:ocorrencia])        
            print(f"Ln Nr: {number}   {line}")

It's a basic solution, but it doesn't solve the issue of comments or strings.
Using pygments is ok too... but i want to separate sentence blocks only ...
from pygments.lexers.dotnet import CSharpLexer
from pygments.token import Token

def tokenize_dotnet_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        code = file.read()
    
    lexer = CSharpLexer()
    tokens = lexer.get_tokens(code)

    for token in tokens:
        token_type = token[0]
        token_value = token[1]
        print(f"Type: {token_type}, Value: {token_value}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "./program.cs"  
    tokenize_dotnet_file(file_path)


this is better but i need the sentences and not the tokens.

What about removing all comments first, then doing what you are doing in your first solution.
with open("./program.cs", "r") as f:
    no_comments = []
    prg=[]
    for number, line in enumerate(f): 
        no_comments.append(line.replace(r'^\s*\/\/',""));
    for number, line in enumerate(no_comments): 
        prg.append(f"<#<{number}>#>{line}")       
    dotnet_lines=re.split(r'[;\{\}]',"".join(prg))
    for i in range(len(dotnet_lines)):
        dotnet_lines[i] = dotnet_lines[i].replace("\n","")
        dotnet_lines[i] = re.sub(r'(.)(\<#\<[0-9]+\>#\>)',r'\1',dotnet_lines[i])
    # Result....
    for ln in dotnet_lines:
        ocorrencia=ln.find('>#>')+3
        line=ln[ocorrencia:]
        number=re.sub('[<#>]','',ln[:ocorrencia])        
        print(f"Ln Nr: {number}   {line}")

Not tested, and not efficient, but I include this above code to clarify what I mean.

Yes thanks. solves part of the problem, leaving comments on multiple lines and strings... As I only need to validate the "statements", if there is a statement in a string it should also be ignored. Strings can also be on multiple lines.
